# Roles authorization with Rails 3 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, roles, cancan

I have used devise ever since i got over to Rails 3, that was around the first or second beta, and now i also needs some Roles. After searching the web it looked like CanCan should be the best solution. But i'm unsure if CanCan can manage my needs, like i want a forum moderator who can edit/destroy the topic, but the user who created the topic should also be able to edit, so how can i do that?

Comment: what about the roles within Devise, can you use that at all?  There is either the simple 'admin_flag' solution or the whole roles object route that allows multiple roles for same user.  All on the Devise github site.  they may have added this more recently.  I don't know CanCan though.  Maybe you have a requirement that makes that the option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your brief description above, I'd imagine CanCan should be able to handle your needs.

CanCan is primarily simplified syntax to centralize authorization rules.  It doesn't provide roles out of the box.  However, the [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki) has a bunch of very useful links, including a [simple](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) and a [more complex](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model) approach to implementing roles.

I have found it helpful to model ownership directly rather than trying to have an "owner" role.  So (assuming you use the simpler role scheme above) the use case you describe above would be modelled in your Ability definition thus:

```
def initialize(user)
  ...
  can :manage, Topic if user.is? :moderator
  can :manage, Topic { |topic| if (topic.user_id == user.id) }
  ...
end
```

Hope this helps.